# how to create excel sheet using windows phone 8.1

Tags: excel, windows-phone-8.1

Is it possible to create an Excel Sheet in Windows phone 8.1.

I can't find any reference for Windows phone 8.1, only for 8.0.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` as the backend is of c#

Or a simpler approach would be to create `HtmlTable` object and manipulate whole of the table. Now convert this table into a stream and use this stream to generate your excel